# redirect http to https for some page in site in APACHE

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to one of my site's page will use only HTTPS.

I have given manually link to all sites to `https`.

But I want that if user manually types that page URL with `http` then it should be redirected to `https` page.

So if user types:

```
http://example.com/application.php
```

then it should be redirected to

```
https://example.com/application.php
```

Thanks
Avinash

Answer (score 8):

Here's a couple of lines I used in an `.htaccess` file for my blog, some time ago :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  =www.example.com                        
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin*                                     
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on                                               
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$  https://www.example.com/admin/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Basically, the idea here is to :

- determine whether the host is www.example.com
- and the URL is /admin/*

  - Because I only wanted the admin interface to be in https
  - which means this second condition should not be useful, in your case
- and https is off *(i.e. the request was made as http)*

And, if so, redirect to the requested page, using https instead of http.

I suppose you could use this as a starting point, for your specific case :-)

You'll probably just have to :

- change the first and last line
- remove the second one

**Edit after the comment :** well, what about something like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  =mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://mydomain.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Basically :

- using your own domain name
- removing the parts about `admin`

Answer (score 3):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^application\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This rule is intended to be used in the .htaccess file in the document root of your server. If you want to use it in the server configuration file, add a leading slash to the pattern of `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Turn SSL on for /user/login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but /user/login
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

[website](http://www.apk.co.ir)

Answer (score 1):

open httpd.conf or .htaccess file (mod_rewrite not required):

```
# vim httpd.conf
```

Append following line :

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
```